# Bookmarklet to edit current URL

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a simple bookmarklet to take the current URL of my website and refresh it with a couple of changes. For example:

1. Take the current page: http://www.example.com/pages/
2. and change it to: https://admin.example.com/pages/
3. then load that new URL.

I tried searching for a bookmarklet that can do this but I couldn't find one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Even a bookmarklet that does something like this that I can edit to suit my needs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just change `window.location`, e.g.

```js
window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^http:\/\/www\./,'https://admin.')
```

The full bookmarklet would then be:

```js
javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^http:\/\/www\./,'https://admin.');})()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

for the record the complete code for the bookmarklet is:

`javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^http:\/\/www\./,'https://admin.');})()`

Comment: Can also use `window.location.href` or just `location.href` instead of `window.location.toString()`.

Answer (score 7):

For example you could replace a part of the string using the `replace` method with a regular expression.

```
 javascript:location = location.href.replace(/http:/g, "https:" )
```

The above will assign the new string value to the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) and trigger the page reload.

Comment: Mine is a straight to SSL conversion. Kenny's switches sub domain as well. Remember to use the JavaScript sudo protocol in front of the JavaScript, to create a bookmarlet.

Comment: sudo? I guess you are talking "pseudo-protocol" ,  that is that '''javascript:'''    prefix. Seems the replyers do not like copy&paste ready-made examples. Users still have their work cut out.

Comment: @dobit, correct I meant 'pseudo' not 'sudo'.

Answer (score 2):

This one will change the site name

```js
javascript:(function() {document.title=prompt("Enter Page Title");})();
```