# Replace domain in url for publishers academia login

Tags: javascript, authentication, bookmarklet, gateway

When working outside of my university IP domain, I have to use a login server to access publishers websites.
Most url that were of the form `http://pubs.domain.org/XXX.html`are transformed into `http://pubs.domain.org.gateway.university.edu/XXX.html`

The problem is: most publishers websites have a useless search tool, so I use google and land on the regular website, and using Web of Knowledge outside of the university often fails to connect to the publisher. I have found that replacing manually the URL works as long as I have authentified in the last hour.

I am searching for a way of using a bookmarklet to do this automatically. I have found this question that seems to be what I'm looking for, but I never used javascript before and have been unable to adapt it.
[Bookmarklet to edit current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689553/bookmarklet-to-edit-current-url)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
javascript:(function() {
  window.location.href =
    location.protocol 
    + '//'+location.hostname
    + '.gateway.university.edu'
    + location.pathname
    + location.search;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this exact situation myself recently. As you want to append a suffix to the hostname, but otherwise leave the URL intact, you can edit window.location.hostname directly to trigger a reload:

```
javascript:window.location.hostname += '.gateway.university.edu';
```

or with closure:

```
javascript:(function() {
  window.location.hostname += '.gateway.university.edu';
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("://pubs.domain.org","://pubs.domain.org.gateway.university.edu");
```